# git force file line ending on commit

Tags: git

We have multi-platform project, which generates binaries for few platforms say mac, windows, linux... Is it possible to force git to change encoding of all files to some particular platform (For example: Linux). So how to change file's line ending every time when users commit or push to remote repository?

Comment: Why would you ever want to change the encoding of a binary? Encoding is not applicable to binaries, only to text files.

Comment: Not for binary but we have configuration files...for which i want to force

Comment: For us, binary will never be in git repository.

Comment: Are you talking about line endings or encoding (like UTF-8)?

Comment: Have you had a look at the setting `core.autocrlf`?

Comment: can we add it to remote repository, So anybody clone, and while committing all get converted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend setting `core.eol` directives in [`.gitattributes` file](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes), rather than relying on a global config like `core.autocrlf`.

```
core.eol
```

> Sets the line ending type to use in the working directory for files that have the text property set.
>   Alternatives are `lf`, `crlf` and **`native`**, which uses the platform's native line ending.
>   The default value is native.
>   See [gitattributes(5)](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes.html) for more information on end-of-line conversion.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you should use a `git hook`, check this scripts: [Git companion scripts by yaegashi](https://github.com/yaegashi/git-companion-scripts).