# Apply patch to file that's under Git without using Git?

Tags: git, diff, patch

I checked out the latest OpenSSL from Git:

```
git clone git://git.openssl.org/openssl.git
```

One of the devs sent me a patch for AARCH64 to test:

```
$ cat RT4237.diff 
diff --git a/crypto/ec/asm/ecp_nistz256-armv8.pl b/crypto/ec/asm/ecp_nistz256-armv8.pl
index 9d1bce1..ce6b69e 100644
--- a/crypto/ec/asm/ecp_nistz256-armv8.pl
+++ b/crypto/ec/asm/ecp_nistz256-armv8.pl
@@ -1289,6 +1289,9 @@ $code.=<<___;
    stp $acc0,$acc1,[$rp_real,#$i]
    stp $acc2,$acc3,[$rp_real,#$i+16]
 ___
+$code.=<<___   if ($i == 0);
+   adr $bp_real,.Lone_mont-64
+___
 }
 $code.=<<___;
    ldp $acc0,$acc1,[$ap_real,#$i]  // in1
```

The patch does not apply using Git. I'm not sharing the Git failure so folks don't get distracted on solving Git problems. Instead, I simply want to use a tool that actually works.

I've tried using [Apply Patch File to a Source Code Tree](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/12/patch-command-examples/) (***`patch -p3 < RT4237.diff`***) but its resulting in errors due to the Git preamble:

```
$ cd openssl
$ patch -p3 < RT4237.diff
(Stripping trailing CRs from patch; use --binary to disable.)
can't find file to patch at input line 5
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/crypto/ec/asm/ecp_nistz256-armv8.pl b/crypto/ec/asm/ecp_nistz256-armv8.pl
|index 9d1bce1..ce6b69e 100644
|--- a/crypto/ec/asm/ecp_nistz256-armv8.pl
|+++ b/crypto/ec/asm/ecp_nistz256-armv8.pl
--------------------------
```

How can I apply the patch ***without using Git***?

---

```
hikey:openssl$ pwd
/home/jwalton/openssl
hikey:openssl$ find . -name RT4237.diff 
./RT4237.diff
hikey:openssl$ find . -name ecp_nistz256-armv8.pl
./crypto/ec/asm/ecp_nistz256-armv8.pl
```

Comment: What errors _exactly_? If you've checked out the _correct_ branch, and the diff is valid for it, it _should_ work [assuming the `-p` level is correct] or give you a list of hunks it couldn't apply. Also, what do you mean by "git preamble"? Do you mean line 1 (ie. the "diff" which shouldn't matter as patch skips over that). Or, just delete the first line from blah.diff

Comment: @CraigEstey - *"What errors exactly?"* - the error message has been added. *"Also, what do you mean by "git preamble""* - the preamble is ***`diff --git ...`***. Its shown in line one of the patch I received.

Comment: per Craig's point about -p, patch's complaint about not finding the file to patch makes me think your cwd isn't lining up with -p3

Comment: Can you show `find . -name ecp_nistz256-armv8.pl` ?

Comment: FWIW `git apply --ignore-whitespace patch`, with `patch` being the diff copy-pasted from the question, whitespace damage'n'all, onto a freshly-cloned repo at 04b76df3f, worked fine for me just now...

Comment: Thanks @Notlikethat. I spent about 45 minutes trying to get that to work. After wasting that kind of time on a simple task, I decided to move onto a tool that worked in practice.

Comment: Oh, absolutely. Thanks to experience with an old Exchange server that loved corrupting mailing list patches, I wouldn't have fought with Git for more than about 45 _seconds_ before giving up and hand-applying everything ;) I was just curious about the failure mode you didn't want to mention, but I guess Git must have got cleverer between the ancient Ubuntu-LTS-packaged versions and the tip-of-tree 2.7 I built the other week out of want for new features.

Comment: @Notlikethat News from 2022 - we now do `conda install -c conda-forge git` to get the latest released version on all platforms. Hip kids use `mamba` of course ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the `pwd` and patch file's contents, the patch needed to be applied with the `-p1` flag to tell patch to ignore the leading "a/" portion of the path name in order for it to find the file to patch:

```
$ cd openssl
$ patch -p1 < RT4237.diff 
(Stripping trailing CRs from patch; use --binary to disable.)
patching file crypto/ec/asm/ecp_nistz256-armv8.pl
$
```

Comment: And worth mentioning.... neither ***`-p0`*** nor ***`-p3`*** work to apply the git patch. This answer sure beats Git, which cost me 45 minutes in man pages, Stack Overflow and U&L.SE searches for how to make the Git ignore the whitespace that it was complaining about. Its classic Git *modus operandi* - take a simple task, and make it difficult. (And no, *`--ignore-whitespace`* and friends did not work).

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can tell, a git patch is a regular diff with preamble. 
Therefore, remove the git preamble and try again.