# git buggy modified files when changing branches

Tags: git, git-branch

I have the craziest bug going on with my repo I don't know what to do. In my repo I have three branches.

```
master > branch_1 > branch_2
```

**From branch_1**

`git status` and all is clear no files are staged or modified.

**From branch_2**

`git checkout branch_2` and type

`git status` again and all of a sudden I have these two files that are marked as `modified`

**What I've tried**

I try to do a git checkout on both these files but they keep re-appearing as modified automatically

**Only special setup:**
The only thing special about these files is that they are part of a `git subtree` repo within this repo.

What's going on here?

**OS** windows 8.1

**git** version 1.9.4.msysgit.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for:

- your .gitattributes files in that branch for any [`core.eol` directives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14772232/6309), which can change the end-of-line character on checkout.
- the [execution bit on those files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4770223/6309) (which should be reset by a git reset --hard, as suggested in [DrewT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1958998/drewt)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25579205/6309) (upvoted)

Those are the two reason which usually lead to "differences" on a checkout.

Answer (score 2):

I would sanity check that you don't have the files open somewhere else on your computer. A code editor may be saving a cached copy of the file in memory. Once you're sure you have nothing open, you can start looking into other options:

- run `git stash pop` - maybe the files had been stashed at some point with `git stash` and now it's a few commits ahead and behaving buggy
- you could always try `git reset --hard` which should throw away all uncommitted changes.

Comment: I rebooted my machine twice and still the same problem, I will try your other suggestions thanks