# How do I determine file encoding?

Tags: git, encoding

Is there a `git` command that returns file encoding like `file` in Linux?
That completely describes my problem. I tried searching Google but found nothing.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: How is this related to git?

Comment: @MrTux I want to get file encoding with git command. How is related to git?

Comment: Note that the `file` command can only guess at a file's encoding. In general, there is no way to perfectly detect file encodings.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Git itself has no idea of the encoding of a file (stored as a blob, meaning as an arbitrary binary data).
See "[What is the format of a git “blob”?](http://web.archive.org/web/20201023205409/http://www.gitguys.com/topics/what-is-the-format-of-a-git-blob/)".

The command file can still be used after a `git checkout`.
Or piped after a [git show](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/27/get-a-file-from-a-specific-revision.html) to read the content of a specific file, e.g.:

```
$ git show @~2:README.md | file -
/dev/stdin: ASCII text
```

tells that the file `./README.md` 2 commits ago had an ASCII encoding - notice the last dash (`-`) denoting STDIN.

While this command:

```
$ git show :README.md | file -
/dev/stdin: Unicode text, UTF-8 (with BOM) text, with CRLF line terminators
```

tells that the same file staged in git's 'index' is gonna be Windows encoded.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to convert line endings (CRLF (Windows) to Linux Standards or else) only, you can try something like this, answered by @VonC [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771414/git-force-file-encoding-on-commit).

Or if you want to convert the encoding from files (i.e.: ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8) and you are a linux user, you could try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052199/convert-git-repository-file-encoding), answered by @Celada

> You can do this with
>
> ```
> git filter-branch
> ```
>
> The idea is that you have to change the encoding of the files in every commit, rewriting each commit as you go.
>
> First, write a script that changes the encoding of every file in the repository. It could look like this:
>
> ```
>     #!/bin/sh
>     find . -type f -print | while read f; do
>         mv -i "$f" "$f.recode.$$"
>         iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8  "$f"
>         rm -f "$f.recode.$$"
>     done
> ```
>
> Then use
>
> ```
> git filter-branch
> ```
>
> to run this script over and over again, once per commit:
>
> ```
> git filter-branch --tree-filter /tmp/recode-all-files HEAD
> ```
>
> where /tmp/recode-all-files is the above script.
>
> Right after the repository is freshly upgraded from CVS, you probably have just one branch in git with a linear history back to the beginning. If you have several branches, you may need to enhance the git filter-branch command to edit all the commits."

Comment: Yes, I've already found this and this is not I want. I just want to get file encoding with git. Of course I can do it with bash commands as I pointed in question.