# diff showing only the diff color without change code

Tags: gitlab

I have changed line  of a sql file file. But the diff only shows the diff colour without any change code.
the line is: @enabled=0, before the change we had 1 instead of 0.

without the gitattribute

```
*.sql text diff
```

I get the error message that file suppressed by a .gitattributes entry or the file's encoding is unsupported.

[this is the link of the image of my git diff] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgMvv.png)

Comment: Is the file stored as UTF-8, or as UTF-16-LE (as Windows does)? Though if it is UTF-16-LE it's a bit surprising that you can see anything at all.

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed an encoding problem!

Comment: @O98 Well spotted. I have edited the answer to illustrate how you can see encoding differences between two version of a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check your `git status` (assuming the `@enabled=0` was done on your workstation)

Check if:

- the file is indeed `Test/Scripts/ScriptsIgnoredOnImport.sql`
- there is any local commit which would *not* have been pushed yet.

The file on GitHub can also tell you more, by typing <kbd>b</kbd> (which triggers the file "`blame`" view on GitHub).
As [shown here](https://github.com/refined-github/refined-github/issues/2175), you can then "View blame prior to this change" and see if your `@enabled=` was visible *then*.

---

As [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74655016/diff-showing-only-the-diff-color-without-change-code#comment131781733_74655016) by [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek), you could have a difference in encoding as well.
As I mentioned in "[How do I determine file encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25700274/6309)", you can (even in a simple CMD on Windows), check the encoding of your current file with:

```
git show :your/file.sql | file -
# compare it with the previous version
git show @~your/file.sql | file -
```